# Fractional part function and greatest integer function

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $f (x)= \{x\} [x]$; $g(x)=ax^2$ the sum of all real solutions of equation satisfying $f(x) = g(x)$ is 420 (where a is (+ve) rational number), then a is equal to (where [.] and {.} represents greatest integer function and fractional part function respectively

A) $\frac{28}{900}$

B)$\frac{29}{900}$

C)$\frac{31}{900}$

D)$\frac{37}{900}$

Comment: Please solve anyone please help me

Comment: So, just to be clear, you're defining $f(x)$ is the *product* of floor(x) and the fractional part of x?  Like $f(\pi) \approx 3 \times 0.141593 \approx 0.424778$?

Comment: This seems like an interesting problem, but you should show some attempt to solve it, or people will vote to close your question.

Comment: Note that since this is a multiple-choice question, a valid approach is to plug in each of the given options for $a$, and see if there's one that satisfies the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n = \lfloor x \rfloor$ and $r = \{x\} = x - n$ be the integer and fractional parts of $x$.

The equation $f(x) = g(x)$ then becomes $nr = a(n + r)^2$.  Or equivalently,

$$ar^2 + (2an - n)r + an^2 = 0$$

We can solve for $r$ with the quadratic formula.

$$r = n \frac{1 - 2a \pm \sqrt{1 - 4a}}{2a}$$

(The requirement that all numbers involved be real gives us the constraint $a \le \frac{1}{4}$, but all of the answer choices satisfy this anyway.)

But, by definition of the fractional part, we know $r \in [0, 1)$.  Thus,

$$0 \le n \frac{1 - 2a \pm \sqrt{1 - 4a}}{2a} < 1$$
$$0 \le n (1 - 2a \pm \sqrt{1 - 4a}) < 2a$$
$$0 \le n < \frac{2a}{1 - 2a \pm \sqrt{1 - 4a}}$$

This gives us a constraint on the possible values for $n$ (and thus on $x$).  For brevity, let $m = \frac{2a}{1 - 2a \pm \sqrt{1 - 4a}}$.  Let $x_n$ be the solution to $f(x) = g(x)$ corresponding to a choice of $n$ within this range.  Then we are given:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} x_i = 420$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (n + n \frac{1 - 2a \pm \sqrt{1 - 4a}}{2a}) = 420$$
$$(1 + \frac{1 - 2a \pm \sqrt{1 - 4a}}{2a}) \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} n = 420$$
$$(1 + \frac{1}{m}) \frac{m(m-1)}{2} = 420$$
$$(m+1)(m-1) = 840$$
$$m^2 - 841 = 0$$
$$m = 29$$

Now that we have our upper bound $m$, let's solve for $a$.

$$\frac{2a}{1 - 2a \pm \sqrt{1 - 4a}} = 29$$
$$2a = 29(1 - 2a \pm \sqrt{1 - 4a})$$
$$2a = 29 - 58a \pm 29\sqrt{1 - 4a})$$
$$60a - 29 = \pm 29\sqrt{1 - 4a})$$
$$(60a - 29)^2 = 29^2(1-4a)$$
$$3600a^2 - 3480a + 841 = 841 - 3364a$$
$$3600a^2 - 116a = 0$$
$$a(3600a - 116) = 0$$
$$a = 0 \lor a = \frac{116}{3600} = \frac{29}{900}$$

Since $a = 0$ is not a valid solution, we must have $\boxed{a = \frac{29}{900}}$.